# Why does my freehub body have such shallow lockring threads?

Tags: cassette, freehub, campagnolo

My new freehub body (right) has much shallower threads than my old one (left). The threads are so shallow that I cannot properly install the cassette lockring.

[image: Freehubs]

They are both for Campagnolo 9/10/11 speed. I am using the standard lockring that came with my Campagnolo 11 speed cassette.

How can I fix this?

Comment: That is odd.  Are they both authentic campag parts or is one of them aftermarket ?   Are you positive the new one isn't for 12 speed?  Visually it looks like the chromed bearing surface is higher than on the original part, needs some careful measurement to confirm that.

Comment: They are both Ritchey freehub bodies for Campagnolo cassettes. Perhaps the new one is defective?

Comment: It looks like the guts have been pushed outwards. Are the insides screwed in?

Comment: @MaplePanda I am unable to disassemble or shift anything by hand. If it has been pushed around it must have taken considerable force! The bearings both spin smoothly.

Comment: I doubt this is the case, but is there *any* chance the new freehub body is one of the N3W bodies? @Criggie you may be referring to this type of body, which is for 13-speed rather than 12s groups. The N3W bodies are truncated so that cassettes with 9 or 10t first cogs can fit, but you can fit an adapter to fit regular 11t cassettes. However, I wasn't aware that the lockring thread depth was changed with this design. It does indeed look like the guts have somehow been pushed out.

Comment: The spec says it is 10/11 speed not "N3W"

Comment: I think I’d contact the seller then. Upon second inspection, you can see how the bearing in the new freehub is not seated in as deep as the old one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very strange one. According to Ritchey, a superfluous dust guard was installed in error on a batch of these freehub bodies. The good news is that the dust guard is only held in with friction, so it can be removed with a pair of pliers. Following this, the freehub body works great!

[image: dust cap removed]

Assembly instructions for the hub can be found [on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aMYb3-KjbbA).

---

For Google:

Ritchey product code for the freehub body is `SKU 55350007013` and for the "WCS Zeta Disc Wheels" it's `SKU 51355008002`.

Comment: So they accidentally stacked two of those rubber dust guards over each other? I guess you now have a spare one ;)

Comment: the correct dust guard is just a thin washer. it's like the combined the wrong parts

Answer (score 4):

The right hand one appears to have been assembled incorrectly. You may be able to fix this by pushing the bearing home with a suitable press but you'd be better off referring the problem back to the supplier of the part who will likely exchange it.

Which of the two routes you take depends very much on where the part came from and how you want to spend your time. It is very frustrating when new parts arrive in this condition!